# SQL: посчитать количество одинаковых записей

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица:

```
id - int(11)
data - date 
url - text
ip - text
username - text
referer - text
```

Задача следующая: вывести из таблицы информацию за определенную дату, при этом сгруппировав по полю `url`

То есть сейчас запросом

```
$stat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stat WHERE data = '".$data."'");
```

Вывожу например такие данне

```
1   2014-07-30  obmennik.ws 46.175.214.225  ref arashvg
2   2014-07-30  obmennik.ws 46.175.214.225  ref arashvg
3   2014-07-30  e-dengi.org 62.76.46.3  ref arashvg
4   2014-07-30  e-dengi.org 42.119.216.151  ref arashvg
5   2014-07-30  e-dengi.org 42.119.216.151  ref arashvg
6   2014-07-30  obmennik.ru 178.93.108.202  ref arashvg
```

Мне же нужно получить:

```
1   2014-07-30  obmennik.ws (2) 
2   2014-07-30  e-dengi.org (3)
3   2014-07-30  obmennik.ru (1)
```

Как такое можно получить?

Comment: про GROUP BY что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Как-то так, наверное: "SELECT data,url,count(id)  FROM stat WHERE data = '".$data."' group by data,url"

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!

Comment: > следуйщуя

!!!

Comment: data - date 
    url - text
    ip - text

Это просто праздник какой-то :)